# How do I delete sessions when a user logs out Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm learning Django. I created the Sign out function. But when I loop with for it gives an error.

*My Code:*

```
def logout(request):
    for key in request.session.keys():
        del request.session[key]

    return redirect('login')
```

But get this error ? I am using Python 3. Can you help me ?

```
RuntimeError at /logout/
dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying a collection over which you are iterating is *tricky*, and frequently not allowed. It can easily result in problems, since the iterator is usually implemented under the assumption that the collection will not change.

You however do *not* need to iterate over the keys here. You can use the [**`clear()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.clear):

```
def logout(request):
    request.session.clear()
    return redirect('login')
```

This is however not sufficient. Django already made a function to logout a user that will clear the session, delete it, etc. [**`logout(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout). You thus can implement this as:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout

def logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked, thanks. No need for auth logout. Because I'm taking data from another web service.

Comment: This answer is useful but I need to know where can I use request.session.modified = True? @Willem